# Finding where in Ramsey's theorem one uses the Axiom of choice

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Ramsey's Theorem for infinite graphs requires some choice but when looking at the proof it is not evident how choice is exactly used. 

Sketch of the proof:
Given $c:[\omega]^2\rightarrow 2$ a coloring we construct a homogeneous set as follows. Inductively we set $a_0=0$ and $S_0=\omega$ then one has that $S_0$ is partitioned into $H^0_0\{a\in S_0\setminus\{a_0\}:c(\{a,a_0\})=0\}$ and $H^0_1\{a\in S_0\setminus\{a_0\}:c(\{a,a_0\})=1\}$ we set $S_1$ to be $H^0_0$ if it's infinite and $H^0_1$ if it's not. And we set $a_1$ to be the minimum of $S_1$. We define analogously $a_{n+1}$ and $S_{n+1}$ from $S_n$ and $a_n$. Given then the set $\{a_n:n\in \omega\}$ we have that for a given $n$ then for all $m>n$ $c(\{a_n,a_m\})$ is constant of color $i_n$. This defines a function $\omega \rightarrow 2$ so we take the preimage of $0$ if it's infinite other we take the preimage of $1$.

I know I am wrong but none of the steps seem arbitrary since both $\omega$ and $2$ are well ordered I can always choose a least element. So where exactly is the axiom of choice needed in this proof? Since the graph version is equivalent to the fact that $\aleph_0$ has the tree property I am assuming it has to do with the existence of the "branch" $S_n$.

Comment: You are assuming the graph is countable?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes,  the coloring is on the unordered pairs of distinct elements in $\omega$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ramsey's theorem for *countably infinite* graphs (or even just *Dedekind-infinite* graphs) does not require choice. It's only when we try to formulate it for *arbitrary infinite* graphs that choice comes into play.

Specifically, if we want to prove "For every infinite set $X$ and every $c:[X]^2\rightarrow2$, there is an infinite $H\subseteq X$ such that $c\upharpoonright [H]^2$ is constant," we need to first **find a copy of $\omega$ inside $X$** (in order to run the argument in the OP). But the statement "Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset" requires choice in a pretty clear way.

---

Incidentally, it's worth keeping in  mind - just as a basic reality-checking mechanism - that choice (and the continuum hypothesis, and etc.) **cannot possibly** be relevant to any sufficiently concrete theorem. Specifically, $\mathsf{ZFC+GCH}$ (+ even more!) proves exactly the same $\Pi^1_2$ sentences as $\mathsf{ZF}$; this is (a special case of) **Shoenfield absoluteness**. And Ramsey's theorem for $\omega$ is prima facie $\Pi^1_2$, so right off the bat we know that choice can't be needed for it.

Is Shoenfield overkill here? Oh my goodness yes. But set theory has so  many counterintuitive aspects that I really do think it is a useful thing to keep in mind, even when not necessary, simply to assure yourself that there are really no secret applications of choice lurking in an apparently-simple argument. In particular, **I think it's totally appropriate to treat Shoenfield as a blackbox** for now; it will still serve a purpose.

Comment: Thanks  I was convinced I was wrong. I'm assuming the same holds for the more general theorem $\omega\rightarrow (\omega)^k_n$ using the same exact argument since the induction step is the same and the set of colors is also well ordered.

Comment: @aldodecristo Yup, although you need the set of colors to be **finite**, not merely well-ordered: Ramsey's theorem with $\omega$-many colors is false.

Comment: Yes other wise I could color each number with a different color and each homogeneous set would have at most one element. Thanks.